# Trying to implement a link to open when a menubar item is clicked but getting an error

Tags: java, javafx

Using HostServices.

I am using the constructor

```
HostServices services = this.getHostServices();
```

I want it to work with the following menu item so that when that menu item is clicked it should open a link to the web browser...
the piece of code i want the object **services** to work on is

```
MenuItem fbMenuItem = new MenuItem("Facebook Page");
    fbMenuItem.setId("fbMenuItem");
    fbMenuItem.setOnAction(event -> {
        services.showDocument("facebook.com");
    });
```

I have imported the

```
import javafx.application.HostServices;
```

which is supposed to work with **HostServices** but I keep getting an error that says

```
Caesar.java:359: error: cannot find symbol
    HostServices services = this.getHostServices();
                                ^
symbol: method getHostServices()
1 error
```

But when I try same procedure with a normal button that is not in  a menuBar it works fine but when I use that trick above on the menuBar it still gives me that error

Comment: [getHostServices() is a method of Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getHostServices--).  You can only call this.getHostServices() in a class which extends Application.

Comment: OK, then how can i make a sort of a link button that when clicked will open a web browser but that button will be located within a menu-bar as a menu-item

Comment: You could pass a HostServices object to the constructor of your `Caesar` class.

Comment: but HostServices does not work with a class that does not extends application. where will i declare that constructor? be straight.

Comment: *Retrieving* a HostServices object via the getHostServices() method only works in a class that extends Application.  The HostServices object itself works anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to create a singleton to hold these kinds of references and then instantiate that during the Application Start Up.

For example:

```
public class HostServiceWrapper {
     private static HostServiceWrapper _instance;
     private HostServices hostServices;

     private HostServiceWrapper (HostServices hostServices) {
        // Do not allow this to be created externally
        if (hostServices == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Host services can't be null to instantiate this method");
        }
        this.hostServices = hostServices;
     }

     public static void createInstance(HostServices hostServices) {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new HostServiceWrapper (hostServices);
        }
     }

     public static HostServiceWrapper getInstance() {
        if (_instance== null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("HostServiceWrapper has not been correctly instantiated.");
        }
        return _instance;
    }

     public void openURL(String url) {
        hostServices.showDocument(url);
    }

}
```

Then in your application start method you would do something like this...

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    .....
     HostServiceWrapper.createInstance(getHostServices());
}
```

Then where you need to access it....

```
HostServiceWrapper.getInstance().openURL("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Ok will try and give feedback